# What does Positional-only parameters do in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pep570

What below python code does?

```py
def pow(x, y, z=None, /):
    r = x**y
    if z is not None:
        r %= z
    return r
```

Comment: have you tried running it?

Comment: You can read [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/) for a full description, but essentially the parameters before `/` cannot be passed by name (e.g. you cannot do `pow(x=1, y=2)` or `pow(y=2, z=3, x=1)`), but instead they must be passed by position, in the order specified by the signature.

Comment: It does the same thing as an ordinary function in earlier versions. It just prevents you from calling the function with parameters in a different order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's already define in [Positional-only parameters](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters) in official documentation in Python 3.8.

> There is new syntax (/) to indicate that some function parameters must be specified positionally (i.e., cannot be used as keyword arguments). This is the same notation as shown by help() for functions implemented in C (produced by Larry Hastings’ “Argument Clinic” tool). Example:
>
> Now pow(2, 10) and pow(2, 10, 17) are valid calls, but pow(x=2, y=10) and pow(2, 10, z=17) are invalid.

See [PEP 570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570) for a full description.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify the value of a positional-only paramter with a keyword argument when you call the function. `pow(1, 2, 3)` will work; `pow(x=1, y=2, z=3)` will not.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty well described in [PEP-0570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/). If forbids using named parameters for parameters marked as positional-only:

```
>>> pow(x=5, y=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: pow() takes no keyword arguments
```

You can only call it like `pow(5, 3)`.